# Единый Configmap для нескольких сервисов

Tags: kubernetes

Подскажите, каким образом можно зашэрить `configmap` между несколькими сервисами?

Например, есть такой:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: urls-config
data:
  BACKEND_URL: "http://backend:8080/"
```

Как мне `BACKEND_URL` подцеплять из общего хранилища средствами куба?

Comment: Вроде, как к одному подключать, так же и к другим -- configmap общий. Или в каком смысле хранилища? адрес что меняется? если меняется, то зачем? может его не менять, а сделать, чтоб на сервис указывал.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю можно задать его как environement при создании Deploy, например вот так:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: some-image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: frontend
          env:
            - name: BACKEND_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: BACKEND_URL
                  name: urls-config
```

PS Код выше не польный, описывает только чать шаблона контейнера, касающегося environement